# (Alexa) Lambda function timeout when using DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-vpc

I have followed the documentation to set up persistence to my Alexa skill. But no matter what I did I'm getting a timeout error.

My lambda function is given full DynamoDB access privileges. Yet a table was not created. Even when I manually created the table I still got the same timeout error and the table was not updated.

Note that I'm using the default VPC with my lambda function. Could this be the issue? If yes how can I add my table to the VPC?

I have no clue at this point and any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected the problem was with the VPC.

DynamoDB resides on the public Internet and therefore my lambda function which was in the VPC had no access to it. Thankfully this can be solved by creating a simple VPC endpoint for DynamoDB.

This blog post by Amazon gives the necessary steps on creating a VPC for DynamoDB
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoints-for-dynamodb/